# []= method always returns a value, even if I override

Tags: ruby

Probably missing something obvious, but I don't understand why the `[]=` method always returns whatever I pass into `value` instead of the `true` or `false` that I specify. Is there something special about the `[]=` method that I'm missing?

Here's some sample code in `irb`, followed by the class definition:

```
irb(main):003:0> aa = ArrayAssignmentTest.new
=> #<ArrayAssignmentTest:0x007feef3119d08 @data=[0, 0, 0, 0]>
irb(main):004:0> aa[0] = 5
=> 5
irb(main):005:0> aa[0] = 1234
=> 1234
irb(main):006:0> aa.inspect
=> "#<ArrayAssignmentTest:0x007feef3119d08 @data=[5, 0, 0, 0]>"
irb(main):007:0> aa[0]
=> 5
```

Class definition:

```
class ArrayAssignmentTest
  def initialize
    @data = [0, 0, 0, 0]
  end

  def [](index)
    @data[index]
  end

  def []=(index, value)
    if (0..99).include?(value)
      @data[index] = value
      return true
    else
      return false
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot override the return value of `=` or `[]=`. Or rather, you can return whatever you want, but it has no affect on the calling code.

The semantics of `a = b[3] = c` is not this...

```
b[3] = c
a = [b]3
```

It is this:

```
b[3] = c
a = c
```